# Any known issues with implementing the legacy camera on Huawei P8?

Tags: android, camera

I've had some reports from the field that my Camera app doesn't work on Huawei P8. The camera is freezing and the `MediaRecorder` doesn't work. Camera preview seems to be choppy and once the `MediaRecorder` is started, the preview freezes completely. I'm using legacy camera APIs and `MediaRecorder` with `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH` profile. I am also setting video size on the `MediaRecorder` `mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mOptimalVideoSize.width, mOptimalVideoSize.height);`, but right now I don't have the logs showing which width/height was set here.

Errors that I'm seeing from the log:

```
03-16 16:02:06.170    2776-3345/? I/HwaStatInfoï¹• [d39e516_I] isTafCapture ,isTafCapture 0
03-16 16:02:06.170    2776-3345/? I/HwaPPExecuterï¹• [d39e516_I] dumpPPStatInfo,  mOrientation = 0, mCameraId = 0, mBeautyLevel = 7, mPictureWidth = 4160, mPictureHeight = 2336, mIspOutWidth = 0, mIspOutHeight = 0,      mPreviewWidth = 1280, mPreviewHeight = 720, mIsDualCamera = 0, mFrameCount = 1
03-16 16:02:06.190   2776-18168/? I/AntiBandingï¹• [d39e516_I] setBandingMsgToDriver() Really set banding msg to miniIsp
03-16 16:02:06.190    2776-3344/? I/ImagingSystemï¹• void hw::CAltek6045Controller::setAntibandingMsg(uint32_t, uint32_t). outcome = 61, threshold = 60
03-16 16:02:06.190    2776-2949/? I/ImagingSystemï¹• int hw::CAltek6045Controller::executeConfig(const hwextisp_config_data_t&) restricted cmd:0x400810ae
03-16 16:02:06.190   2776-18164/? I/ï¹• [SmartAfAlgo_Grace_1.0.33]test: bHoldToMove = 0, iMovingFrmCnt = 0, mPreFrmResult = 8, mResult = 8
03-16 16:02:06.190   2776-18164/? I/ï¹• [SmartAfAlgo_Grace_1.0.33]int SMARTAF::smartAfAlgo::rect_protected(HWAF_TYPE), mFocusRect[0, 0, 0, 0]
03-16 16:02:06.190   2776-18164/? I/ï¹• [SmartAfAlgo_Grace_1.0.33]int SMARTAF::smartAfAlgo::rect_protected(HWAF_TYPE), preview_width: 1280 preview_height: 720
03-16 16:02:06.190   2776-18164/? I/ï¹• [SmartAfAlgo_Grace_1.0.33]int SMARTAF::smartAfAlgo::rect_protected(HWAF_TYPE), rect[560, 280, 160, 160]
03-16 16:02:06.190   2776-18163/? I/HwaStatInfoï¹• [d39e516_I] isTafCapture ,isTafCapture 0
03-16 16:02:06.190   2776-18164/? I/ï¹• [SmartAfAlgo_Grace_1.0.33]diff[contrast,lum,ae][rbratio, xyz] = [23 2 99][0 2 16 23]
03-16 16:02:06.190   2776-18164/? I/ï¹• [SmartAfAlgo_Grace_1.0.33]af result is 8.
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18173/? W/CFilterDownscaleï¹• virtual hw::TRetCode hw::CFilterDownscale::receive(hw::IBuffer*): instance[0xaaf44120], drop.
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18169/? W/CFilterDownscaleï¹• virtual hw::TRetCode hw::CFilterDownscale::receive(hw::IBuffer*): instance[0xab0a0bc0], drop.
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/ThumbnailHWï¹• Src base(0xf0b08000) size(3112960, w1920 h1080); Dest base(0xf2c1e000) size(1843200)
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• src->w      = [1920]
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• src->h      = [1080]
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• src->format = [17]
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• src->base   = [0xf0b08000]
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• src->handle = [0xaae28068]
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• srcHandle->format [17]
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• dst->w      = [1280]
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• dst->h      = [720]
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• dst->format = [20]
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• dst->base   = [0xf2c1e000]
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• dst->handle = [0xaaeb3fc0]
03-16 16:02:06.200   2776-18168/? I/libcopybitï¹• dstHandle->format [20]
03-16 16:02:06.200    2776-3345/? I/HwaStatInfoï¹• [d39e516_I] isTafCapture ,isTafCapture 0
03-16 16:02:06.200    2776-3345/? I/HwaPPExecuterï¹• [d39e516_I] dumpPPStatInfo,  mOrientation = 0, mCameraId = 0, mBeautyLevel = 7, mPictureWidth = 4160, mPictureHeight = 2336, mIspOutWidth = 0, mIspOutHeight = 0,      mPreviewWidth = 1280, mPreviewHeight = 720, mIsDualCamera = 0, mFrameCount = 1
03-16 16:02:06.210   3000-18083/? I/CameraEventHandlerï¹• virtual void hw::CameraBufferStuckHandler::handleMessage(const android::Message&)(129): instance[0xab07e148].
03-16 16:02:06.210   3000-18083/? I/CameraEventHandlerï¹• [I/DMD] open dev -1
03-16 16:02:06.210   3000-18083/? E/CameraEventHandlerï¹• I/DMD: open dev fail
03-16 16:02:06.210   3000-18083/? I/Camera3Deviceï¹• virtual void hw::Camera3Device::onError(int)(588): instance[0xaaed8650].
03-16 16:02:06.210   3000-18083/? E/Camera3-Deviceï¹• Camera 0: notifyError: Camera HAL reported serious device error
03-16 16:02:06.210   3000-18083/? E/Camera2Clientï¹• Error condition 1 reported by HAL
```

Are there any known issues on that device? As usual, it's probably the parameters set on the camera or maybe the media recorder profile, but unfortunately I don't have the physical device and can't really start fixing this blind.

Comment: did you have any luck?

Comment: no, never came back to this issue - too much of an edge case really. have you tried what Joel suggested in the answer?

Comment: I am unable to open Camera on like all huawei models, Ascend, Honor, P'X', G'XXX'. I thought there might be a special setting before opening camera on these devices

Comment: I'm also getting a lot of reports from my users that my app doesn't work on "huawei" devices

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Huawei honour 7. Once I removed the MediaRecorder.setVideoSize, it turns out normal.